# How to resolve non rendering DataTable export buttons?

Tags: jquery, css, datatables, datatable-buttons

I'm following a [guide on adding file export](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html) `buttons` to an existing DataTable.

But when I run the asp solution the export buttons work as expected but they don't render correctly, showing only the text for the buttons.

I've re-checked the order of the script references which mirror the set up of the guide linked above.

**Question:**

What is the correct order of scripts in order to render DataTable buttons?

What they look like at runtime:

[image: export buttons]

What they should look like:

[image]

Scripts and HTML (gist):

```
@model System.Data.DataTable


<div class="container">
    <hr/>



        <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <div class="table-responsive" id="datatable-wrapper">
                            <style>
                                #escalation tr > *:nth-child(1) {
                                    display: none;
                                }
                            </style>
                            <table id="escalation" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                                        {
                                            <th style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #7591ac; ">@col.Caption</th>
                                        }
                                        <th style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #7591ac; ">Details</th>
                                        <th style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #7591ac; ">Delete</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows)
                                    {
                                        <tr>
                                            @foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
                                            {
                                                <td style="font-size:11px">@cell.ToString()</td>
                                            }
                                            <td><button type="submit" style="background-color: #0CA281;" class="btn btn-success details">Details</button></td>
                                            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger delete">Delete</button></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    }
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>



    $(document).ready(function () {



        var historyTable = $('#escalation').DataTable({
            "order": [[6, "desc"]],
            buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
            ],
            "sSwfPath": "../Content/dataTables/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf"          
        });

        historyTable.buttons().container()
        .insertAfter( '#datatable-wrapper' );




    });
</script>
```

Comment: could you please post your HTML too?

Comment: @vijayP I posted my HTML now above..still not sure what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the [DOM parameter](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/#dom-parameter):

```
 order: [[6, "desc"]],
 dom: "Bfrtip",
 buttons: [
    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
]
```

More info about this parameter [Here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom), hope it helps!

Update:
You could use the [Datatables download builder](https://datatables.net/download/) and include the buttons extension. Just make sure you include the relevant css (I'm assuming the builder includes it). Just in case, [This is the minified version of the buttons css](https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css)

Comment: that didn't solve the problem, I think that prop just specifies the location of the toolbar relative to my table. Any other ideas?

Comment: Updated the answer.  I actually thought it was working for me, but it wasn't. Adding the relevant css was enough for me.